# Cryptic Error When Ember.js Component Loads for Second Time

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to render a component called `stat-table` into the following template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="table">
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>

    {{stat-table rows=rows}}
</script>
```

Where `rows` is the `Table` model's `hasMany` relationship to the `row` model. Here's the component template (it's `tagName` is `"table"`):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/stat-table">
    {{#each rows}}
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

the first time the component is loaded, it renders perfectly. However, if I switch to a different view (the table view with the `stat-table` component is un-rendered) and then switch back, I get the following cryptic error in my console:

```
Uncaught #<error>             ember.js:73
```

I did some snooping using the `init` function of the `statTableComponent`, included below:

```
App.StatTableComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: "table",
    classNames: ["stat-table"],
    init: function() {
        this._super();

        this.get("rows")
        .then(function(rows) {
            console.log(rows);
        });
    }
});
```

In the code above, the error fires before the promise for `rows` has resolved. The error might be occurring because the `#each` helper is trying to iterate over the promise for `rows` before it has resolved, but I'm not sure why that would only happen after the second time the view loads...

How can I get the component to load without a hitch every time it is rendered?

**Update--Full Stack Trace of Error:**

```
Uncaught #<error> ember.js:73
    Ember.assert ember.js:73
    (anonymous function) ember.js:30066
    sendEvent ember.js:2599
    Ember.Evented.Ember.Mixin.create.trigger ember.js:18317
    superFunction ember.js:7723
    Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.trigger ember.js:22507
    superWrapper ember.js:1292
    Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.triggerRecursively ember.js:24061
    superWrapper ember.js:1292
    (anonymous function) ember.js:25652
    Ember.EnumerableUtils.forEach ember.js:1932
    ViewCollection.forEach ember.js:22611
    insertViewCollection ember.js:25649
    Ember.merge.ensureChildrenAreInDOM ember.js:25635
    Ember.ContainerView.Ember.View.extend._ensureChildrenAreInDOM ember.js:25587
    DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js:6127
    Backburner.end ember.js:6215
    Backburner.run ember.js:6254
    Ember.run ember.js:6664
    Ember.EventDispatcher.Ember.Object.extend._bubbleEvent ember.js:22294
    (anonymous function) ember.js:22243
    n.event.dispatch jquery.js:4409
    r.handle jquery.js:4095
```

Comment: What's rows, and what's the rest of the component code look like?

Comment: added more info as requested.

Comment: The console error message should be expandable into a stack trace; what do you see? Line 73 is nothing more than where the failing assertion is printed out. Failing that, set the Chrome devtools flag to stop on errors and you should be able to see the stack trace.

Comment: I added the full stack trace--hopefully that helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing your `<tbody>` tag for your table http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html.

Comment: 1 question though: technically you don't need a `<tbody>` tag for an html table to be valid--why do I need one in this case?

Comment: The html spec says you don't need it, but almost browsers will inject it in there for you (Check out the source).  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bunoreso/1/edit

Comment: So then I wonder why Ember would throw an error when it wasn't explicitly included...

Comment: I don't know if I ever saw the reason why they enforced it, it probably was in the PR somewhere, but I never read it.